# Fedex Account Not Saving

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, fedex

This is sort of a follow up to another thread, since the issue is kind of its own issue compared to how I discovered the error.

I'm testing Fedex for Sandbox, but when I enter the sandbox account # and meter # . .  .they don't save.   I can see this is in the shipping log, where my original production account and meter number are being used with the NEW key and password.  I am entering all of these at the same time and of course saving, though obviously the meter and account # are NOT saving, or somehow it is defaulting back to my actual production account and meter #.

Not surprisingly fedex says that the account number is wrong.

So, I figure if I can get the account number saved properly I will have the issue licked.   Anyone heard of anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this. Its when you dont have the php library installed for encryption - mcrypt I believe it is.  Because under the hood its encrypting the password/details as you store them. Sounds like this is failing.